# Destiny PS4 Will all add ons work with regular disc copy

Tags: destiny

I recently purchased destiny the legendary edition (physical copy) which has all the add on content and what not. I downloaded all of the stuff and codes in the case to my playstation and was playing fine. My little brother got a hold of the disc copy and managed to crack it :(. Now it no longer works. My question is if i buy just a used disc copy of destiny will the add ons still work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes all the DLC will still work with any copy of Destiny, Digital or a Physical disc.

The copy of Destiny that comes with the Legendary Edition is actually the same disc as the regular edition that launched a year ago.

Source: Personal experience, I traded my launch day copy of Destiny for The Taken King Legendary Edition. The disc was the same but the DLC download codes were included in the box.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion for similar reasons but want to add that you can test this but renting a copy from the library or whatever.